# android gcm push notifications randomly opening app

Tags: android, notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging

We have a weird bug in our app. Our app is designed to receive GCM push notifications and open the app to a particular activity depending on the payload of the notification when the notification is clicked. This all works fine except that on rare occasions (as in I've triggered 500+ push notifications and have only seen it happen twice) our app will open itself seemingly without user intervention. It almost seems as if something is triggering the notification in the notification bar. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any idea as to what might be causing this? I've pretty thouroughly searched Google and StackOverflow but I have only found one question about similar behavior with no answers which can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112479/push-notification-is-opening-app-directly

I've included the BroadcastReceiver, the IntentService, and the intent-filters from the manifest below.

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(comp));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**IntentService:**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {            
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(gcm.getMessageType(intent)))
                sendNotification(extras.getString(GlooIntents.GLOO_URL), extras.getString(GlooIntents.ALERT));
        }

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String url, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("nextPath", url);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_home));
        builder.setWhen(when);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name_replace_me));
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".GroupActivity"
    android:label="@string/group"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data
            android:host="app"
            android:pathPattern="/groups/.*"
            android:scheme="gloo" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?